# understanding CPU step by step journey of learning process

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture

hello
I want to learn how cpu works from scale of bit level to assembly level
could somebody tell me ?
which one would be better? 
top-down learning or bottom-up learning?
and what am I suppose to do first?
assembly language? or computer architecture?
what sort of book, site, method would be good?
I am interested in computer science/Artificial Intelligence but I have no compass to know how to get there efficiently 
your reply would be very thankful and helpful

welcome your experienced story
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do well reading [something like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032124656X) in combination with the Intel/AMD Instruction manuals, of course this is biased to x86, but other vendors/architectures should have similar publications.

This does go very in-depth, but that can only serve to help in my opinion.
Also, if your interests are AI and CS, this could be considered a waste of time, as it'll add to neither ([remember CS is not about programming, its about the art of programming and programatic problem solving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science)).

Comment: If you go from down up, you probably have to learn about integrated circuits to understand how CPUs are actually designed, implemented and tested. Assembler is way too high level.